replication lag between data centers
I am facing replication lag in postgres16 at times, not able to find the reason.
Please find the configuration:

Two replication slots for two servers (one is on the same data center, another remote)
weekly once/twice facing lag(around 2GB for 1k TPS environment) in the remote   replication slot and another same data center server slot with 0 lag.

My observations:

Noticed pg_stat_replication_slot total_txn reduced from 1000 to around 10 TPS but other  slot withing same data center is same with 1k TPS
2)And noticed lag for remote slot but fine with same data center
Most importantly I have plenty of Bandwidth available in n/w ,2GB is still freely available out of 4GB network.
4)No IO issues on servers
Trying to understand the reason for delay.

At least how the logical decoding total_txn is counting the view pg_stat_replication_slot does it stops decoding if any lag?

The question is lacking detail. How exactly is replication set up? Any locks?

Most of the time, replication lag is related to network or resource issues.
Apart from the bandwidth, you can check for latency or packet loss which can impact replication performance. You can use ping, traceroute, or iperf to evaluate network status.
It can be a configuration issue, but if it’s working fine in the same DC, I’d focus on the network or resources.

Does pg_stat_replication_slot stops decoding when lag noticed?

Not really @satya k. It continues regardless of the lag, as long as the replication connection remains healthy.  But, if there are network issues it can affect the decoding process until connectivity is restored.
